# Virtuoso DBpedia load - parsing errors

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso, rdfstore

I have a lot of errors when I want to load DBpedia dataset. For example:

```
 22007 XM003: XML parser detected an error:     ERROR  : Tag nesting
 error: name 'img' of end tag does not match the name 'p' of start tag
 at line 4 column 432 at line 4 column 438 of source text
 04/02/skos/core#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"></img></p>
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Ok, let's find the line where the error occured (I put a line break, so it is easier to see):

```
<http://core-project.kmi.open.ac.uk/data-description> <http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/encoded> "<h2 xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:foaf=\"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/\" xmlns:og=\"http://ogp.me/ns#\" xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\" xmlns:sioc=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#\" xmlns:sioct=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#\" xmlns:skos=\"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\">What data are exposed</h2>\n<p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:foaf=\"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/\" xmlns:og=\"http://ogp.me/ns#\" xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\" xmlns:sioc=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#\" xmlns:sioct=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#\" xmlns:skos=\"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\">The CORE project exposes data about the aggregated content. The following schema shows the kind of metadata CORE holds about each resource. </p>\n<h2 xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:foaf=\"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/\" xmlns:og=\"http://ogp.me/ns#\" xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\" xmlns:sioc=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#\" xmlns:sioct=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#\" xmlns:skos=\"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\">Data Schema</h2>\n<p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:foaf=\"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/\" xmlns:og=\"http://ogp.me/ns#\" xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\" xmlns:sioc=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#\" xmlns:sioct=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#\" xmlns:skos=\"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\"></img></p>
    \n<h2 xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:foaf=\"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/\" xmlns:og=\"http://ogp.me/ns#\" xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\" xmlns:sioc=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#\" xmlns:sioct=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#\" xmlns:skos=\"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\">Data License</h2>\n<p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:content=\"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:foaf=\"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/\" xmlns:og=\"http://ogp.me/ns#\" xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\" xmlns:sioc=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#\" xmlns:sioct=\"http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#\" xmlns:skos=\"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\">All data from CORE (unless otherwise specified) are available under the a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License. </p>\n"^^<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral> .
```

Why the heck Virtuoso tries to check HTML/XML tags consistency inside the literals?! Is it possible to turn it off? I have too many errors in the dataset, it is a waste of time trying to find all lines with errors and remove them by hands.

Comment: which DBpedia dataset? can you be more specific?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it is BTC 2014 dataset. nevertheless, it does not matter. the problem is in HTML/XML tag inconsistency in the RDF literal shown above.

Comment: to be more precise, I think the problem is in the literal type specification: ^^<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral>
after removing it, no error is shown. I.e. Virtuoso tries to check if the content inside the literal is XMLLiteral consistent. How to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Your main question is why Virtuoso tries to check whether the lexical form you've shown us can be parsed as correct XML content.  Virtuoso does this because it tries to conform to [the RDF 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-XMLLiteral).

According to that specification, if the datatype of an RDF literal is `rdf:XMLLiteral`, then the lexical form should be "well-balanced, self-contained XML content" (per XML 1.0).